# What can be a good solution to strengthen this multiply() BigDecimal operation in order to handle the possibility of null values?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, bigdecimal

in my code I have the following code involving a **multiply()** operation on  two**BigDecimal** values

```
walletsDTOList.stream().forEach( (WalletDTO wallet) -> {
    try {
        ConversionPriceDTO conversionPriceDTO = coingeckoInfoService.getCoinPrice(wallet.getCoin().getName(),targetCurrency);
        BigDecimal conversionRate = conversionPriceDTO.getPrice();
        conversionPriceDTO.setPrice(wallet.getAmount().multiply(conversionRate));
        wallet.setConvertedCurrencyAmountInfo(conversionPriceDTO);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException | BindingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeBindingException(e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

This line:

```
conversionPriceDTO.setPrice(wallet.getAmount().multiply(conversionRate));
```

Now my problem is that the **wallet.getAmount()** coming from the DB and it could be **NULL**. The problem is that in case of **NULL** value I obtain the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.math.BigDecimal.multiply(java.math.BigDecimal)" because the return value of "com.easydefi.users.dto.WalletDTO.getAmount()" is null
```

I need to toughen up this operation. For my **NULL** value equals to 0 so in this case the multiply operation must return 0.

What can be a smart way to do it? My idea was to put the previous line (containing the multiply() operation) into a try catch and in case of **NullPointerException** set 0.

Is it good or can I do better?

Comment: Why not modify `wallet.getAmount()` to return BigDecimal.ZERO when it would otherwise be null?

Comment: Throwing NPE when receiving null is the right thing to do.  If null is supposed to represent zero, then you should actually pass in zero instead of null.

Comment: By the way, `throw new RuntimeBindingException(e.getMessage())` should be `throw new RuntimeBindingException(e.getMessage(), e)` to make debugging less frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a different NPE in the same block of code, catching it and assuming that it was thrown because `getAmount` returned `null` will hide some other bug.

Either change `getAmount` to never return `null`, or do something like:

```
final BigDecimal walletAmount = wallet.getAmount();
conversionPriceDTO.setPrice(
        walletAmount == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO
                             : walletAmount.multiply(conversionRate)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
final BidDecimal amount = Optional.ofNullable(wallet.getAmount()).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
...
```